# aria tabs - VO cursor does not follow programatic focus

Tags: accessibility, voiceover

I've been working on adding aria to an existing tab interface which uses url hashes (or fragments) to aid in sharing links to specific tabs. Ie, `tabs.html#tab2` would show tab2 on page load.

I've been trying to follow best practices for tab accessibility as outlined by https://medium.com/@LeonieWatson/danger-testing-accessibility-with-real-people-4515f72db648

However, all of the examples that I have found for accessible tabs remove hash change functionality (the URL does not change when a tab is activated). When trying to implement it myself I ran into an odd issue. When VO is on and the VO cursor is on a tab, the VO cursor will not follow keyboard navigation to other tabs. Instead, focus will be directed immediately back to the tab with the VO cursor (preventing tabs from being read). This problem does not happen when VO is turned off (presumably because there is no VO cursor).

**Notes**

- This only appears to happen in Safari
- I haven't tried in other screen readers
- All of my VO settings are in their default state

**Examples:**

- Video demonstration of the issue: https://youtu.be/SkQ_vcJiIMI
- Code example: https://gist.github.com/mfairchild365/9b2ba49ec87bd38bb34a433edd994a71 (note this code is not mine, I'm simply using it as an example with slight modifications)
- Live example: https://mfairchild365.com/temp/aira-tabs/tabs.html#home

**What I have tried:**

- sending focus to the currently selected tab before and after the hash change
- an ugly hack where I remove the hash ID from the body before the hash change and add it back after
- `preventDefault()` in both the `click` and `hashchange` event handlers

None of which worked. No matter what I do, I can not get the VO cursor to follow keyboard navigation for tabs.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I jumped the gun and assumed that the issue was due to VO not following programmatic focus. The REAL issue appears to be either a VO or browser bug and is actually CSS related. See my example page here: http://mfairchild365.github.io/aria-tabs-vo-bug/

I'd like to understand why a single CSS rule is having such an impact. If you can answer this, please open an issue in my example repo.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure whether this may be related, but I couldn’t help noticing that if you open [your example code](https://mfairchild365.com/temp/aira-tabs/tabs.html) in Safari and then click on any of the text within the page, you’ll see a blinking cursor. (You can also see the cursor blinking in your video.)

On the other hand, the [code example from the article that you linked to](http://a11yideas.com/testcode/tabs/tabs_with_ARIA.html) doesn’t seem to do that. (That is, you don’t see a blinking cursor if you click on the text in the page.) So that seemed a little odd.

And just to toss out an unrelated idea, is there any chance that your keydown code might be susceptible to a race condition if someone were to hold down one of their arrow keys?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I agree it is odd that the blinking cursor is shown in one example but not the other. That might be part of the issue, and I don't fully understand why it is doing that. My understanding was that the blinking cursor actually shows the location of VOs focus: it is the 'VO cursor'.

That being said, I think I was misled when investigating this issue. Please see my answer.